# Scala - call method on upper bounded instance

Tags: scala, oop, generics, types, scala-generics

In the code below, there's a DogSearcher which has a method called fetch that expects a Ball. We could also have a CatSearcher with a fetch method that expected a Bell. The idea is that we can call fetch on an instance that inherits from PetSearcher and provide different arguments to it.

Any idea what I'm missing?

```
trait PetSearcher {
  def search(what: Thing): Unit = {
    println("default searching")
  }
}

class DogSearcher extends PetSearcher {
  def search(what: Ball): Unit = {
    println("dog searching")
  }
}
trait Thing {
  val name: String
}
case class Ball(name: String) extends Thing

class Pet {
  def fetch[S <: PetSearcher, F <: Thing](searcher: S, what: F): Unit = {
    println(what)
    searcher.search(what)
  }
}

class Dog extends Pet {
  val searcher = new DogSearcher()
  val ball = new Ball("red")
  def go(): Unit = {
    fetch[DogSearcher, Ball](searcher, ball)
  }
}

//should use DogSearcher but calls fetch on Search, not on DogSearcher. 
// So prints default searching, not dog searching..
new Dog().go()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `search` method of DogSearch does not override the `search` method of PetSearcher because the argument types are different (`what` is a `Thing` for PetSearcher but a `Ball` for DogSearcher - the fact that `Ball` extends `Thing` is not enough to make the function calls the same).

Let `PetSearcher` take a type parameter to define the type of `what`, then `DogSearcher` can override this (note the `override` keyword becomes necessary):

```
trait PetSearcher[T] {
  def search(what: T): Unit = {
    println("default searching")
  }
}

class DogSearcher extends PetSearcher[Ball] {
  override def search(what: Ball): Unit = {
    println("dog searching")
  }
}
```

To get it to compile, you also need to update the use of PetSearcher in Pet, by adding the type parameter F (the subtype of Thing that this Pet searches for) to the PetSearcher:

```
def fetch[S <: PetSearcher[F], F <: Thing](searcher: S, what: F): Unit = {
```

Comment: Would there be a way a to say `DogSearcher extends PetSearcher[Ball]` and then have the `search` method know that is supposed to accept a `Ball` without manually adding `Ball` to the method signature? If you had like 20 methods you wouldn't want to be copying `Ball` everywhere

Comment: I don't think so, in scala you must give the type for method arguments. If you want to avoid typing, a good IDE should help, with IntelliJ with the scala plugin, to *override* a method (as in the example, replace the already implemented trait) press ctrl+o and select the method(s) - it will fill in the types (including in this case where the type is derived from the parameter). To *implement* method(s) (i.e. if the trait did not have a default implementation) press ctrl+i (this shortcut is very useful when implementing traits).

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to [@JamesThorniley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41168510/2661491), you could define `search` to accept anything which extends `Thing`:

```
trait PetSearcher {
    def search[T <: Thing](what: T): Unit = {
        println("default searching")
    }
}

class  DogSearcher extends PetSearcher {
    override def search[T <: Thing](what: T): Unit = {
        println("dog searching")
    }
}
```

This outputs `dog searching` as desired.

Comment: Although this would work I actually prefer @JamesThorniley's answer because it constrains what a DogSearcher can search for. Still thank you, this might be useful in other situations

Comment: @Sofia Sure, it all depends on what your use case. If each `PetSearcher` is only supposed to be able to look for a single item type then you would parameterize the class with that type.

Comment: @Sofia also as an aside, `fetch[DogSearcher, Ball](searcher, ball)` can be written as `fetch(searcher, ball)`, adding the types is redundant here.